# Getting optional field out of message in logstash grok filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I´m trying to extract the number of ms in this logline

> 20190726160424 [INFO]
>   [concurrent/forasdfMES-managedThreadFactory-Thread-10] -
>   Metricsdceptor: ## End of call: Historirrtory.getHistrrOrder took 2979
>   ms

The problem is, that not all loglines contain that string
Now I want to extract it optionally into a duration field. I tried this, but nothing happend .... no error, but also no result.

```
 grok
 {
   match => ["message", "(took (?<duration>[\d]+) ms)?"]
 }
```

What I´m I doing wrong ?

Thanks guys !

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply, it matches, but it doesn´t store the number in duration field.  :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to only apply the grok filter on the log lines ending with ms. It can be done using [conditionals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html#using-conditionals) in your configuration.

```
if [message] =~ /took \d+ ms$/ {
   grok {
     match => ["message", "took %{NUMBER:duration} ms"]
   }
}
```

Comment: That would be a solution, but it becomes even worse when I take it a step further and want to extract the method and the unit additionally. It got this working,

`[0-9]{14} \[(?<loglvl>.+?)\].+?##.+?(End of call\: (?<method>.*))?.+?(took (?<duration>[\d]+ (?<unit>\w+)))$`

but not optionally.... means when i change the original message in a way that it doesn´t contain either the method or the duration or the unit it doesn´t work anymore ....
Maybe I should brake it up from the beginning with these conditionals, right...

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why, but it works if you anchor it

```
grok { match => { "message" => "(took (?<duration>\d+) ms)?$" } }
```

Comment: tried it like that "[0-9]{14} .*(took\s)?(?<duration>\d+)(\sms)?" but it doesn´t work either. It matches all occurences, but only stores the last digit in diration field. Tried it here: grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

Comment: Found why it isn´t working for me.... I have to put a "%{MYDATE:timestamp} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglvl}\].*" in front of it, to capture the date also, but when I do that, iti doesn´t work anymore ....

Comment: Hi guys, yesterday I tried to extract the second part of the string "End of call: Historirrtory.getHistrrOrder took 2979 ms" into a field "message_stripped" and then do a second match => in the grok block where I can take out the duration finallly, but somehow a second match with a field which I´ve extracted in the step before doesn´t work either :-(